# SpriteKit how to create and transition to different scenes (Swift language)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, transition

I have created a game with sprite kit but at the moment when the game is launched, it goes straight to the game. How can i implement different scenes like a main menu and a game over scene and transition between them either by pressing a label on the screen or by a contact during the game.

Comment: I solve this problem in swift you can find some code on bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't seem like you have looked into Apple's documentation. They have an excellent guide for SpriteKit. Also, the tutorials at RayWenderlich.com within the spriteKit category are phenomenal. I haven't read much into Swift yet, but it is my understanding that Swift can be written alongside Objective-C.That being said, I'll give you a starting point (in Objective-C) .

1) Calling the initial scene:

Within your main view controller, you will want to cast the VC's `view` property to an `SKView` within `viewDidLoad` like so:

`SKView *spriteKitView = (SKView *)self.view;`

some useful debugging properties on `SKView` :

```
spriteKitView.showsFPS = YES;
spriteKitView.showsNodeCount = YES;
spriteKitView.showsPhysics = YES;
```

You will have to configure each scene separately (subclass `SKScene`). After you have done this, import the main scene to your main VC's class implementation. To present the main scene (still in `viewDidLoad`):

```
MyScene *mainScene = [MyScene new];
[spriteKitView presentScene: mainScene];
```

2) transition between scene via label (or any other `SKNode`) :
Set relevant nodes as properties and present a new scene via:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];

    if ([self.playAgainButton containsPoint:touchLocation]) {
        [self presentGamePlayScene];
    } else if([self.mainMenuButton containsPoint:touchLocation]) {
        [self presentMainMenu];
    }
}


- (void)presentGamePlayScene {
    gamePlayScene *newGamePlay = [[gamePlayScene alloc]init];
    newGamePlay.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
    SKTransition *arbitraryTransition = [SKTransition crossFadeWithDuration:2.0]; //look into SKTransition for a plethora of different options.
    [self.view presentScene:newGamePlay transition:arbitraryTransition];
}
```

3) To change scenes via contact, conform to the protocol `SKPhysicsContactDelegate` within any given `SKScene`. Within that scene's implementation:

```
- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact {
    if(contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == enemyCategory && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == arbitraryNodeCategory) {
        [self presentGameOverScene];
    }
}
```

An `SKPhysicsContact` has 2 colliding `SKPhysicsBody`s attached to it via properties. These colliding nodes must have their `SKPhysicsBody`'s initialized. In addition, they must have their `contactBitMask` property set on their `SKPhysicsBody` like so:

```
@implementation SomeNode 

- (instanceType)initCollidingNode {
     if(self = [super init]) {
         self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:self.someSize];
         self.physicsBody.contactBitMask = enemyCategory | powerUpCategory;
         self.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = arbitraryNodeCategory;
         self.physicsBody.dynamic = YES 
     }
     return self;
}
```

- SKSpriteNode and SKPhysicsBody have other relevant properties you may need

Comment: I don't understand objective-c. Im new in iOS development and i start with Swift but it is hard to find some tutorials.

Comment: Try raywenderlich.com, Apple's book on Swift, or this iOS blog: http://ios-blog.co.uk/swift-tutorials/ -note: objective-c will still be relevant for the foreseeable future.

Comment: This is in Objective C, not Swift, and is therefore not an appropriate answer.

Comment: @BenJammin where is this Apple's documentation for SpriteKit with Swift ? If you mean the official doc it's only for Obj-C. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH2-SW2

^^op you can try this : https://github.com/monchote/spritekit-programming-guide-swift - somebody ported code from the Obj-C guide to Swift but I haven't looked into it.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem in swift.

```
func goToGameScene(){
    let gameScene:GameScene = GameScene(size: self.size) // create your new scene
    let transition = SKTransition.revealWithDirection(SKTransitionDirection.Down, duration: 0) // create type of transition (you can check in documentation for more transtions)
    gameScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill
    self.view!.presentScene(gameScene, transition: transition)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a new swift file called MainMenu.swift

The following code placed in your current scene will allow a transition to the scene described in MainMenu.swift:

```
var scene =  MainMenu(size: self.size)
let skView = self.view! as SKView
skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
scene.size = skView.bounds.size
skView.presentScene(scene)
```

In the new scene, you can use the following code to get back to the scene described in GameScene.swift:

```
var scene =  GameScene(size: self.size)
let skView = self.view! as SKView
skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
scene.size = skView.bounds.size
skView.presentScene(scene)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a file called: TestScene.Swift

Declare it in your GameScene.Swift file and implement the touches function like so:

```
var sceneTest: TestScene!

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    // Configure the view.
    let gameView = self.view as SKView!

    /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
    gameView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

    sceneTest = TestScene(size: gameView.bounds.size)
    gameView.presentScene(sceneTest)
    sceneTest.scaleMode = .AspectFill
}
```

This will present a new scene called TestScene