# Moving between GameScene and ViewController Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, xcode6

I want to move from my GameScene to ViewController, when I touch an Image and back to GameScene when I touch an UIButton.
It worked from ViewController to GameScene, because it is UIButton.

I have done it like this:

```
@IBAction func playbut(sender: UIButton) {
    var scene = GameScene(size: CGSize())
    let skView = self.view as! SKView!
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
    scene.size = skView.bounds.size
    skView.presentScene(scene)
}
```

But I don't know what code to write to go back to ViewController, when I touch that image, which is on GameScene.

What should I write to GameScene?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is what you're expected to do... You should be using an SKScene - instead of a UIViewController - for your navigation/menu.

But, [one post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696420/present-a-uiviewcontroller-from-skscene) I found did explain this (albeit it's in Obj-C):

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone"     bundle:nil];
UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PurchasedVC"];
//Call on the RootViewController to present the New View Controller
[self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The Swift version should look something like this (I'm no expert, but the syntax isn't too bad)...

```
var mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main_iPhone", bundle: nil)
var vc = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PurchasedVC") as! UIViewController
self.view.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

In terms of other answers:

- This is probably the best post I've seen on this topic: [Presenting UIViewController from SKScene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578391/presenting-uiviewcontroller-from-skscene)
- Additionally, I found this one on transitioning between scenes: [SpriteKit how to create and transition to different scenes (Swift language)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24230245/spritekit-how-to-create-and-transition-to-different-scenes-swift-language)

I hope that helps. I had the same question, and to be honest, it looks like I was just doing it wrong the whole time!

Comment: What is the name of UIStoryboard? My Storyboard's name is Main.Storyboard. But if I replace ''Main_iPhone'' with ''Main.Storyboard'' it gives me an error, that Main.Storyboard can't be found. What should I write there?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following.

`let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainController")
        let  vc2 = self?.view!.window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController
        vc2?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)`

Using Constant

`self?.view!.window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController`

we can derive view controller in which our current game scene is running.