# Create Button in SpriteKit: Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I want to create a button in `SpriteKit` or in an `SKScene` that sends the view to another view controller.

I tried using the "performSegue with identifier ", however apparently an `SKScene` doesn't support this. 
How would I create a button that sends the view to another view with `SpriteKit`?

This is the code that I've tried using to perform this action.

The line with "HomeButton.prepareForSegueWithIdentifier()" is just an example. It won't actually let me add the "prepareForSegue" part, it doesn't support it <--- What I mean by that is when I go to add it, it is unrecognized.

```
class GameOverScene: SKScene {

     var HomeButton: SKNode! = nil


    init(size: CGSize, won: Bool) {
        super.init(size: size)

        backgroundColor = SKColor.whiteColor()

        HomeButton = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.blueColor(), size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
        HomeButton.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        HomeButton.userInteractionEnabled = true
        self.addChild(HomeButton)

        let message = won ? "You Won!" : "You Lose!"





        let label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Title 1")
        label.text = message
        label.fontSize = 40
        label.fontColor = SKColor.blackColor()
        label.position = CGPoint(x: size.width/2, y: size.height/2)
        addChild(label)

        runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(3.0), SKAction.runBlock() {
            let reveal = SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(0.5)
            let scene = GameScene(size: size)
            self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: reveal)
        }
        ]))


    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            if HomeButton.containsPoint(location) {

                HomeButton.prepareForSegueWithIdentifier()

            }
        }
    }
```

Note: I've tried using a button, but they don't work in and SKScene.

I'll be on to respond if there is any confusion.

Comment: for me works as usual, so i don't know what is your problem with this?

Comment: Could you explain more what you tried to do

Comment: Hey, it would be good if you could post an example of what you have tried and someone might be able to help you figure out what isnt working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you need to create a button in `SpriteKit`, I think this button must have all or some of the available actions to do whatever you want (exactly as `UIButton` did)

Here you can find a simple class that build a SpriteKit button, called FTButtonNode:

```
class FTButtonNode: SKSpriteNode {

    enum FTButtonActionType: Int {
        case TouchUpInside = 1,
        TouchDown, TouchUp
    }

    var isEnabled: Bool = true {
        didSet {
            if (disabledTexture != nil) {
                texture = isEnabled ? defaultTexture : disabledTexture
            }
        }
    }
    var isSelected: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            texture = isSelected ? selectedTexture : defaultTexture
        }
    }

    var defaultTexture: SKTexture
    var selectedTexture: SKTexture
    var label: SKLabelNode

    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("NSCoding not supported")
    }

    init(normalTexture defaultTexture: SKTexture!, selectedTexture:SKTexture!, disabledTexture: SKTexture?) {

        self.defaultTexture = defaultTexture
        self.selectedTexture = selectedTexture
        self.disabledTexture = disabledTexture
        self.label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Helvetica");

        super.init(texture: defaultTexture, color: UIColor.whiteColor(), size: defaultTexture.size())
        userInteractionEnabled = true

        //Creating and adding a blank label, centered on the button
        self.label.verticalAlignmentMode = SKLabelVerticalAlignmentMode.Center;
        self.label.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.Center;
        addChild(self.label)

        // Adding this node as an empty layer. Without it the touch functions are not being called
        // The reason for this is unknown when this was implemented...?
        let bugFixLayerNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: nil, color: UIColor.clearColor(), size: defaultTexture.size())
        bugFixLayerNode.position = self.position
        addChild(bugFixLayerNode)

    }

    /**
     * Taking a target object and adding an action that is triggered by a button event.
     */
    func setButtonAction(target: AnyObject, triggerEvent event:FTButtonActionType, action:Selector) {

        switch (event) {
        case .TouchUpInside:
            targetTouchUpInside = target
            actionTouchUpInside = action
        case .TouchDown:
            targetTouchDown = target
            actionTouchDown = action
        case .TouchUp:
            targetTouchUp = target
            actionTouchUp = action
        }

    }

    /*
    New function for setting text. Calling function multiple times does
    not create a ton of new labels, just updates existing label.
    You can set the title, font type and font size with this function
    */

    func setButtonLabel(title: NSString, font: String, fontSize: CGFloat) {
        self.label.text = title as String
        self.label.fontSize = fontSize
        self.label.fontName = font
    }

    var disabledTexture: SKTexture?
    var actionTouchUpInside: Selector?
    var actionTouchUp: Selector?
    var actionTouchDown: Selector?
    weak var targetTouchUpInside: AnyObject?
    weak var targetTouchUp: AnyObject?
    weak var targetTouchDown: AnyObject?

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        if (!isEnabled) {
            return
        }
        isSelected = true
        if (targetTouchDown != nil && targetTouchDown!.respondsToSelector(actionTouchDown!)) {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction(actionTouchDown!, to: targetTouchDown, from: self, forEvent: nil)
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        if (!isEnabled) {
            return
        }

        let touch: AnyObject! = touches.first
        let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(parent!)

        if (CGRectContainsPoint(frame, touchLocation)) {
            isSelected = true
        } else {
            isSelected = false
        }

    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        if (!isEnabled) {
            return
        }

        isSelected = false

        if (targetTouchUpInside != nil && targetTouchUpInside!.respondsToSelector(actionTouchUpInside!)) {
            let touch: AnyObject! = touches.first
            let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(parent!)

            if (CGRectContainsPoint(frame, touchLocation) ) {
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction(actionTouchUpInside!, to: targetTouchUpInside, from: self, forEvent: nil)
            }

        }

        if (targetTouchUp != nil && targetTouchUp!.respondsToSelector(actionTouchUp!)) {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().sendAction(actionTouchUp!, to: targetTouchUp, from: self, forEvent: nil)
        }
    }

}
```

The source is available in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/richy486/5d408c442ac1c0c2891f)

**Usage**:

```
let backTexture: SKTexture! = SKTexture(image:"backBtn.png")
let backTextureSelected: SKTexture! = SKTexture(image:"backSelBtn.png")  
let backBtn = FTButtonNode(normalTexture: backTexture, selectedTexture: backTextureSelected, disabledTexture: backTexture,size:backTexture.size())
backBtn.setButtonAction(self, triggerEvent: .TouchUpInside, action: #selector(GameScene.backBtnTap))
backBtn.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
backBtn.zPosition = 1
backBtn.name = "backBtn"
self.addChild(backBtn)

func backBtnTap() {
    print("backBtnTap tapped")
    // Here for example you can do:
    let transition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(0.5)
    let nextScene = MenuScene(size: self.scene!.size)
    nextScene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
    self.scene?.view?.presentScene(nextScene, transition: transition)
}
```

Comment: Could I do it to where it sends it to a viewController, rather than another SKScene?

Comment: Sure, my answer its just an example, if you dont know how look this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/30041939/1894067

Answer (score 12):

I have translated Alessandro Ornano’s answer to Swift 3.1:

```
import SpriteKit

class FTButtonNode: SKSpriteNode {

enum FTButtonActionType: Int {
    case TouchUpInside = 1,
    TouchDown, TouchUp
}

var isEnabled: Bool = true {
    didSet {
        if (disabledTexture != nil) {
            texture = isEnabled ? defaultTexture : disabledTexture
        }
    }
}
var isSelected: Bool = false {
    didSet {
        texture = isSelected ? selectedTexture : defaultTexture
    }
}

var defaultTexture: SKTexture
var selectedTexture: SKTexture
var label: SKLabelNode

required init(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("NSCoding not supported")
}

init(normalTexture defaultTexture: SKTexture!, selectedTexture:SKTexture!, disabledTexture: SKTexture?) {
    
    self.defaultTexture = defaultTexture
    self.selectedTexture = selectedTexture
    self.disabledTexture = disabledTexture
    self.label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Helvetica");
    
    super.init(texture: defaultTexture, color: UIColor.white, size: defaultTexture.size())
    isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    
    //Creating and adding a blank label, centered on the button
    self.label.verticalAlignmentMode = SKLabelVerticalAlignmentMode.center;
    self.label.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.center;
    addChild(self.label)
    
    // Adding this node as an empty layer. Without it the touch functions are not being called
    // The reason for this is unknown when this was implemented...?
    let bugFixLayerNode = SKSpriteNode(texture: nil, color: UIColor.clear, size: defaultTexture.size())
    bugFixLayerNode.position = self.position
    addChild(bugFixLayerNode)
    
}

/**
 * Taking a target object and adding an action that is triggered by a button event.
 */
func setButtonAction(target: AnyObject, triggerEvent event:FTButtonActionType, action:Selector) {
    
    switch (event) {
    case .TouchUpInside:
        targetTouchUpInside = target
        actionTouchUpInside = action
    case .TouchDown:
        targetTouchDown = target
        actionTouchDown = action
    case .TouchUp:
        targetTouchUp = target
        actionTouchUp = action
    }
    
}

/*
 New function for setting text. Calling function multiple times does
 not create a ton of new labels, just updates existing label.
 You can set the title, font type and font size with this function
 */

func setButtonLabel(title: NSString, font: String, fontSize: CGFloat) {
    self.label.text = title as String
    self.label.fontSize = fontSize
    self.label.fontName = font
}

var disabledTexture: SKTexture?
var actionTouchUpInside: Selector?
var actionTouchUp: Selector?
var actionTouchDown: Selector?
weak var targetTouchUpInside: AnyObject?
weak var targetTouchUp: AnyObject?
weak var targetTouchDown: AnyObject?

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if (!isEnabled) {
        return
    }
    isSelected = true
    if (targetTouchDown != nil && targetTouchDown!.responds(to: actionTouchDown)) {
        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(actionTouchDown!, to: targetTouchDown, from: self, for: nil)
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    
    if (!isEnabled) {
        return
    }
    
    let touch: AnyObject! = touches.first
    let touchLocation = touch.location(in: parent!)
    
    if (frame.contains(touchLocation)) {
        isSelected = true
    } else {
        isSelected = false
    }
    
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if (!isEnabled) {
        return
    }
    
    isSelected = false
    
    if (targetTouchUpInside != nil && targetTouchUpInside!.responds(to: actionTouchUpInside!)) {
        let touch: AnyObject! = touches.first
        let touchLocation = touch.location(in: parent!)
        
        if (frame.contains(touchLocation) ) {
            UIApplication.shared.sendAction(actionTouchUpInside!, to: targetTouchUpInside, from: self, for: nil)
        }
        
    }
    
    if (targetTouchUp != nil && targetTouchUp!.responds(to: actionTouchUp!)) {
        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(actionTouchUp!, to: targetTouchUp, from: self, for: nil)
    }
}

}
```

Usage:

```
@objc func buttonTap() {
    print("Button pressed")
}

override func didMove(to view: SKView)
{
    backgroundColor = SKColor.white
    let buttonTexture: SKTexture! = SKTexture(imageNamed: "button")
    let buttonTextureSelected: SKTexture! = SKTexture(imageNamed: "buttonSelected.png")
    let button = FTButtonNode(normalTexture: buttonTexture, selectedTexture: buttonTextureSelected, disabledTexture: buttonTexture)
    button.setButtonAction(target: self, triggerEvent: .TouchUpInside, action: #selector(GameScene.buttonTap))
    button.setButtonLabel(title: "Button", font: "Arial", fontSize: 12)
    button.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX,y: self.frame.midY)
    button.zPosition = 1
    button.name = "Button"
    self.addChild(button)
}
```

I have created two .png:

[image: button.png]
[image: buttonSelected]

Answer (score 7):

The simplest solution, but possibly not of the greatest quality, is to use a SpriteNode containing an image and name it. Later, using that scene you can easily program it to transfer the user to the next scene when tapped:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
   let button = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "yourImgName")

   override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
      button.name = "btn"
      button.size.height = 100
      button.size.width = 100
      button.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + 50)
      self.addChild(button)

      //Adjust button properties (above) as needed
      }

   override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
      let touch = touches.first
      let positionInScene = touch!.locationInNode(self)
      let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(positionInScene)

    if let name = touchedNode.name {
        if name == "btn" {

            let yourNextScene = YourNextScene(fileNamed: "YourNextScene")
            self.view?.presentScene(yourNextScene!)

          }
      }
   }
}
```

Don't forget to replace "YourNextScene" with the actual name of your next scene.