# SpriteKit creating a button issues

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Im attempting to use some of the code from a solution found on this page for creating a button [Create Button in SpriteKit: Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38192205/create-button-in-spritekit-swift)

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
   let button = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "yourImgName")

   override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
      button.name = "btn"
      button.size.height = 100
      button.size.width = 100
      button.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame) + 50)
      self.addChild(button)

      //Adjust button properties (above) as needed
      }

   override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
      let touch = touches.first
      let positionInScene = touch!.locationInNode(self)
      let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(positionInScene)

    if let name = touchedNode.name {
        if name == "btn" {

            let yourNextScene = YourNextScene(fileNamed: "YourNextScene")
            self.view?.presentScene(yourNextScene!)

          }
      }
   }
}
```

and the current code that I have is supposed to make the player jump when the button is pressed, but nothing is currently happening when its pressed

```
import SwiftUI
import SpriteKit
import UIKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        let button = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "playerOBJ")
        let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "playerOBJ")
        let playerRadius = player.frame.width / 2.0
    
    
        player.position = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 500)
        player.name = "Jimmy"
    
        addChild(player)
    
        player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: playerRadius)
        player.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        player.physicsBody?.friction = 0
        player.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
        player.zPosition = 100
    
        // Button
        button.name = "btn"
        button.size.height = 100
        button.size.width = 100
        button.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
        self.addChild(button)
    
    
        // Physics
        physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: frame.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)))
    
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: true) { _ in
            player.physicsBody?.applyForce(CGVector(dx: 100, dy: 1000))
        }
    
         func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
            let touch = touches.first
            let positionInScene = touch!.location(in: self)
            let touchedNode = self.atPoint(positionInScene)

            if let name = touchedNode.name {
                if name == "btn" {
                    player.physicsBody?.applyForce(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 10000))
                }
            }
        }
    }
    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) { }
}
```

I'm thinking that maybe this is an issue with the press not being resitered at all but I'm not fully sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is you put all of your code inside the `didMove` function. You put the `touchesBegan` function inside the `didMove` function. When the `didMove` function finishes, `touchesBegan` goes away so none of your touches are going to be handled in the game.

You also declared the button and the player as local variables inside the `didMove` function.

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    let button = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "playerOBJ")
    let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "playerOBJ")
    // Rest of function omitted
}
```

When the `didMove` function finishes, the button and player go away too. You also have the same image name for the player and button.

The fix is to make the `button` and `player` variables properties of the `GameScene` class. Move `touchesBegan` out of the `didMove` function too.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    // Declare button and player here.
    var button = SKSpriteNode()
    var player = SKSpriteNode()

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        // Initialize button, player, and everything else here.
    }

    func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        // Code in touchesBegan func goes here.
    }
}
```